# DB Sorting Challenge

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table as follows,

```
A   A  
B   B1  
A   A1  
B   B  
A   A2  
B   B3  
A   A3  
B   B2
```

My result set should be,

```
A   A  
A   A1  
A   A2  
A   A3  
B   B  
B   B1  
B   B2  
B   B3
```

Note: A, A1 are all GUIDs.

I have tried quite a few tricks. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Are those 2 columns or is it 1 column with a space in the value?

Comment: Two columns, but A, A1 are all GUIDs

Comment: @user400638: Don't abstract necessary details from the question, and don't use tabs for formatting in the future.

Comment: why on earth would you care to sort by a GUID? they are just random values!

Comment: This is effectively not a Sort, this is a grouping of them.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that the spaces indicate separate columns.

```
select * from [Table] order by [column1], [column2]
```

If each line is a string then doing an order by [column1] should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something, but I figured this would be:
ORDER BY Column1, Column2

Perhaps you could explain this further?